# Java Spring WebClient request equivalent of curl with multiple --data-raw

Tags: java, curl

Small question regarding a curl request with multiple --data-raw, and how to construct its Java WebClient counterpart please.

I am having a very simple curl request:

```
curl -X GET https://some-url:8080/services/auth/login --data-raw username="some-user" --data-raw password="some-password"
```

The part I am having difficulties with is the **double --data-raw, username="some-user" --data-raw password="some-password"**

I first thought I could wrap them in a JSON, and combine with `.body(BodyInserters.fromValue())` but that is not the case.

```
--data-raw '{"username": "some-user", "password": "some-password"}'
```

I then tried (based on this post comment):

```
webClient.mutate().baseUrl(someUrl).defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE).build().get().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(someRoute).queryParam("username", "some-user").queryParam("password", "some-password").build()).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
```

None of above worked.

How to send this equivalent of this curl request, using Java Spring WebClient please?

Thank you

Comment: curls `-d, --data, --data-raw` implicitly set the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Have you tried setting the content type header in the webclient ?

Comment: (corrected) ... and multiple --data options, each of which should be (and yours are) name=value, are combined with &, which is how x-www-form-urlencoded is defined to work. Note using --data-raw values containing characters that need percent-encoding (yours don't) will cause the server to parse wrong and probably fail.

Comment: Hello both, many thanks for your comments, much appreciated. I edited the original question based on you guys input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, the correct use is:

1. Create a

   ```
   private final MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
   ```
2. On the WebCLient:

   ```
   webClient.mutate().baseUrl("https://...").build().post().uri("/route").headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setAll(headers))
   ```

   Where `headers` is the `formData`